# "The operation has timed out" error when login via DocuSign api in C#

Tags: docusignapi

I'm getting the following error since 31/05/2018 from the DocuSign API on login.

> DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling Login: The operation has timed out'.

We have been testing DocuSign API since last year and it was all working fine with our in-house integrated application. Yesterday was the first time we got this error message in login and the issue is there still. If I login via the demo DocuSign web site https://appdemo.docusign.com, I can log in.
But if I try the same via DocuSign API it gives the timeout error.

`Configuration.ApiClient.Configuration.ApiClient.RestClient.BaseUrl` is set to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/

`new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<string, string>(Configuration.DefaultHeader).Items[0]` is set to 
`{[X-DocuSign-Authentication, {"Username":[username], "Password":[password], "IntegratorKey":[IntegratorKey]}]}`

We haven't changed the username or password or IntegratorKey at all.

The value of `response.StatusCode` is returned as 0. Please find my code for login below.

```
public ApiResponse< LoginInformation > LoginWithHttpInfo (AuthenticationApi.LoginOptions options = null)
    {            

        var path_ = "/v2/login_information";

        var pathParams = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        var queryParams = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        var headerParams = new Dictionary<String, String>(Configuration.DefaultHeader);
        var formParams = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        var fileParams = new Dictionary<String, FileParameter>();
        Object postBody = null;

        // to determine the Content-Type header
        String[] httpContentTypes = new String[] {

        };
        String httpContentType = Configuration.ApiClient.SelectHeaderContentType(httpContentTypes);

        // to determine the Accept header
        String[] httpHeaderAccepts = new String[] {
            "application/json"
        };
        String httpHeaderAccept = Configuration.ApiClient.SelectHeaderAccept(httpHeaderAccepts);
        if (httpHeaderAccept != null)
            headerParams.Add("Accept", httpHeaderAccept);

        // set "format" to json by default
        // e.g. /pet/{petId}.{format} becomes /pet/{petId}.json
        pathParams.Add("format", "json");


        if (options != null)
        {
            if (options.apiPassword != null) queryParams.Add("api_password", Configuration.ApiClient.ParameterToString(options.apiPassword)); // query parameter
            if (options.includeAccountIdGuid != null) queryParams.Add("include_account_id_guid", Configuration.ApiClient.ParameterToString(options.includeAccountIdGuid)); // query parameter
            if (options.loginSettings != null) queryParams.Add("login_settings", Configuration.ApiClient.ParameterToString(options.loginSettings)); // query parameter

        }


        // make the HTTP request
        IRestResponse response = (IRestResponse) Configuration.ApiClient.CallApi(path_, 
            Method.GET, queryParams, postBody, headerParams, formParams, fileParams,
            pathParams, httpContentType);

        int statusCode = (int) response.StatusCode;

        if (statusCode >= 400)
            throw new ApiException (statusCode, "Error calling Login: " + response.Content, response.Content);
        else if (statusCode == 0)
            throw new ApiException (statusCode, "Error calling Login: " + response.ErrorMessage, response.ErrorMessage);

        return new ApiResponse<LoginInformation>(statusCode,
            response.Headers.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value.ToString()),
            (LoginInformation) Configuration.ApiClient.Deserialize(response, typeof(LoginInformation)));

    }
```

Comment: Per [DS Support](https://support.docusign.com/articles/000044869), DocuSign has ended support for TLS1.0 in Demo from May 29th, 2018. As you are saying that nothing even no code changed on your end so check if you are impacted by this or not?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **DocuSign Support Website**
>
> For more details please read the [link](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/End-of-TLS-1-0-and-weak-cipher-support)
>
> [image]

**Code Change**

Please do this following changes (in red box) in your code.

***Quick Fix***

[image]

***Code Line***

```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Please ensure `using System.Net;` exists in your namespace.

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick replies Amit and Ragesh. Your responses helped me a lot in figuring out the issue. Everything worked fine as before after enabling TLS 1.2. Thanks again.

Comment: Offical blog mandating this change: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/End-of-TLS-1-0-and-weak-cipher-support