# DocuSign Login API Timeout Error

Tags: docusignapi

I have a c# DOT NET Winforms application that has been working just fine in the developer environment. Yesterday it just stopped working for some reason. No code changes at all. It seems to be timing out while logging in.

```
private string DocLogin()
    {

        ErrMsg = string.Empty;
        string _accountId = null;

        try
        {
            var _apiClient = new ApiClient(DocuSignURL);
            Config = new Configuration(_apiClient);

            // configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
            string _authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + Username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + IntegratorKey + "\"}";
            Config.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", _authHeader);

            // we will retrieve this from the login API call
            AuthenticationApi _authApi = new AuthenticationApi(Config);
            LoginInformation _loginInfo = _authApi.Login();

            _accountId = _loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _accountId = null;
            ErrMsg = ex.Message;
        }

        return _accountId;

    }
```

As soon as it hits the line "_authApi.Login()" it hangs up then throws the error, "Error calling Login: The operation has timed out".

Any ideas? Remember there has been no code changes and was working fine. I thought about corporate firewall but I tried it outside of the firewall with the same results.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate for [50634774](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634774/the-operation-has-timed-out-error-when-login-via-docusign-api-in-c-sharp), can you please check comments and answer in this post? I think your are also impacted by DocuSign stopped TLS1.0 support issue.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems DocuSign stopped TLS1.0 support. See Amit's post above for the link to the solution.