# Getting One Exception With Docusign While Retrieving Document REST API C#

Tags: c#, rest, docusignapi

I tried to get the Status of an Envelope using RestAPI C#. But im getting one exception Unable to Connect to the Remote server. got the TCP error as 10060.

[image]

this is the code that i have used for getting the completed document.

[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (in text).

Answer (score 0):

Per [DS Support](https://support.docusign.com/articles/000044869), DocuSign has ended support for TLS1.0 in Demo from May 29th, 2018 and will end sopport in PROD from June 25th. If you are not able to connect to DocuSign API for any of the API calls in Demo then it seems you are having this TLS1.0 issue.

Try setting below in your code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Please ensure using `System.Net;` exists in your namespace.

More details available at [50637281](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50637281/3530898)